# using xpath need to get to a child and get another node one level up

Tags: xpath

I am trying traverse through an XML with XPath. I want to visit /group/isRequired[text()='Optional'] and travel one level up to grab the /bool node

I tried a few things like the below but can't seem to get it rit... appreciate any inputs.

I basically want to verify the Library node, group+isRequired node and the bool nodes in one statement.

```
//root/sample[library[text()='2']]/group/isRequired[text()='Optional']//bool[text()='true']
//root/sample[library[text()='2']]/group/isRequired[text()='Optional']../bool[text()='true']
//root/sample[library[text()='2']]/group/isRequired[text()='Optional']/bool[text()='true']
//root/sample[library[text()='2']]/group/isRequired[text()='Optional']/../bool[text()='true']


<root>
<sample>
    <id>1</id>
    <library>2</library>        
    <ruleName>Default</ruleName>        
    <group>
        <groupID>1</groupID>
        <groupName>orange</groupName>
        <isRequired>Optional</isRequired>           
    </group>
    <variant>1</variant>
    <bool>true</bool>
</sample>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move two steps up:

```
/root/sample[library[text()='2']]/group/isRequired[text()='Optional']/../../bool[text()='true']
```

But is much cleaner to put multiple conditions in one predicate:

```
/root/sample[library[text()='2'] and group/isRequired[text()='Optional'] and bool[text()='true']]
```

Comment: tx for suggesting the cleaner option.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
/root/sample[library = "2" and group/isRequired = "Optional" and bool = "true"]
```

You don't have to use `/text()` to get the value of every node in the XPath. Depending on whether you XML has a schema, you don't need to put the literal values in quotes. Without it, everything is a string value, so I put them in quotes just for safety.

Answer (score 1):

You can go a different route, by filtering `sample` node by `group/isRequired` child, then you can continue from that `sample` node to get to the `bool` node :

```
//root/sample[library='2' and group/isRequired='Optional']/bool[.='true']
```